# PHP GET and id bookmark

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I have this code:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] !== "2"){
    die();
} ?>

<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div id='come_to_me'>
   I should be on the top of your page
</div>
```

This isn't really my code, but gets the point across. I need a URL that, when visited, has the correct GET variables and will move down to the `come_to_me` `div`.

www.domain.com/example/?page=2#come_to_me
www.domain.com/example/#come_to_me?page=2

Neither of these seem to work for me.

Comment: `example.com/example/?page=2#come_to_me` should work... unless you encode the `#`, or if there are multiple elements with that id... Or, naturally, when there is no need to scroll the page because it fits, i.e. there are no scroll bars...

Comment: Come to think of it, yes. Just throw a few hundred more `<br>`'s in there, and that will probably fix it...

Comment: Only one id of that name. This suddenly works now though. Maybe I just wasn't paying attention. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test and found:

```
www.domain.com/example/index.html?page=3#come_to_me  Works
```

Answer (score 0):

this url will work: `www.domain.com/example/?page=2#come_to_me`

But you have to create the anchor:

```
<div id='come_to_me'>
   <a name="come_to_me"></a>
   I should be on the top of your page
</div>
```

Comment: # selects anchors based on name?

Comment: Long, long, long ago. `<a name="">`'s are ancient knowledge, no longer needed, and best forgotten.

Comment: @Wrikken in html5 can be id or name, if to user1813212 is not working by id, i assume it's html4...

Comment: Yes, indeed, id's work without any code, without any javascript, yes. Good. That's settled then. Without regards to version BTW. Browsers will happily do it for HTML3 documents.

Comment: I do not understand the -1

Comment: Just fixed that -1, not sure why you got it... :)

Comment: You got the -1 for "you have to create the anchor". _"have to"_ means _must_. And it has been ages since this was needed. It is not needed anymore, you can just skip that thing. Of course, if you _want_ to, you can still add it, it does not hurt. It's just... useless and a waste of time now, since you can already do this by an relevant `id`.